# What kinds of milk are low in carbs?

Tags: milk, low-carb

What kinds of milk are low in carbs? I have heard about coconut milk but I'm not sure what's best.

PS: I am from India, maybe someone might want this info:-)

Comment: Meta on close vote:  http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1771/closing-for-nutrition-or-health-where-is-the-boundary

Comment: Nutrition is off topic here - we won't discuss what you *should* drink as part of any given diet. But the question of carb contents of various milks and milk replacements are (marginally) on topic. So I've edited your question to give you a chance. Feel free to edit further or roll back if you're not happy with it.

Comment: How do you define "low in carbs"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-sweetened almond milk is probably what most people on low carb diets drink, when they drink it. It has < 1g of carb per cup.

Personally, I completely stopped drinking milk because of carbs years ago and I don't look back. I only drink a little bit of half and half with coffee, and even though it still has carbs, it's so little that it makes little difference.

Comment: Almond milk has 4% carb, and 5% fat, same as cows milk more or less

Comment: Just from some quick research, unsweetened almond milk seems to be a lot lower in carbs than dairy. [Almond](http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/custom/278488/2), [Dairy](http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/dairy-and-egg-products/70/2)

Comment: Are you getting carbohydrate percent (per 100 g) or the RDI figure?

Answer (score 10):

Cows, goat, soy, almond, and coconut milk have around the same carbohydrate levels, so there is not enough difference to make the effort to rework recipes etc.

Also coconut milk has more than 20% fat compared to milk having 1% to 5%. A normal human body can use fats as efficiently as sugars, so total energy of coconut milk will be very high

Approximate carbohydrate %, and kJ per 100 g of milk

- [Skim Cow](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cow%20skim%20milk%20100g) ..... 5%, 150
- [Full Cow](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=milk%20100g) ....... 7%, 260
- [Almond](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=almond%20milk%20100g) ........ 4%, 275
- [Coconut](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=coconut%20milk%20100g) ....... 5%, 880
- [Goat](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=goat%20milk%20100g) .............4%, 290
- [Human](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=human%20milk%20100g) ......... 7%, 290
- [Soy](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=soy%20milk%20100g) .............. 6%, 190

Each country, recipe, and supplier will have different figures, these are standardised with Wolfram Alpha, a recognised accurate source, and a neutral source, as they are not involved in the food or dietary industry

In many countries, "standard" milk is homogenised half fat milk, so about half way between skim and full cow milk figures

Comment: Whether or not it makes any sense, it's probably best to stick to the facts about carb content (as opposed to caloric content) - it's what the question is about.

Comment: I cleaned up the health related discussion, especially seeing that the claim which caused it has been edited out of the answer.

Comment: Mammals, including humans, don't generally have the Glyoxylate cycle which would allow them to make sugars from fats. That biochemical pathway is generally reserved for plants, bacteria and fungi: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glyoxylate_cycle

Comment: Good info but it seems to only account for sweetened varieties which will usually be ~1-2% but can be as low as 0.1%. Also worth considering is lactose-free regular milk.

Answer (score 3):

[Unsweetened Almond Milk] - 2g Carb in 1cup (240g),  1g from sugar and 1g from fiber and fiber should be subtracted from your carb count due to how your body processes it.

> [Because fiber doesn't absorb like other carbohydrates, don't count it in your overall intake of carbohydrate.](http://healthyeating.sfgate.com/subtract-dietary-fiber-carb-count-11020.html)

So this would be a NET of **1g Carb** in 240g.  Considering TFD's Almond milk has 4% in 100g leads me to believe that almond milk is sweetened.

Comment: TFD's wolfram alpha link is in fact for sweetened almond milk. The unsweetened matches your numbers. Good catch. FWIW, TFD's post probably has more votes since he included his sources. That's always better than just "because I say so"

Comment: Actually- Almond milk has barely any protein, only a tiny bit of fiber, and a bit of minerals. It's really just almond flavored water. Looking at these numbers has dissuaded me from ever buying the stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a low carb diet then the unsweetened almond milk is obviously the way to go. For those of us looking to add our low carb protein powder to something other than water or regular cows milk, almond milk is a nice solution. Stay low carb, maintain ketosis ;)

Answer (score 1):

Unsweetened Soya alternative to milk has 0.2g per 100g. Though I wish someone would come up with a way to separate the carbohydrate (sugar) out of cow's milk...

Comment: Given that lactose free milk is marketed, such a way most certainly exists!

Answer (score 0):

Silk unsweetened Almond Milk is 1 carb .per  1/2 cup . I use the,  Silk almond  milk with my 1 carb mocha high protein powder by Vega and some ice in blender and with a cup or two of water and make a big chocolate mocha shake that is 2 carbs. I try to keep my carbs at 10 a day.

Comment: Hi Grace. What do you mean by "1 carb"? The standard unit of carbohydrate is the gram, and it is pretty clear from your description that you are not using that. So please add the unit, else your answer is very confusing.

Comment: @rumtscho : I tried using the nutrition fact labels ... but Silk Unsweetened Almond is listed as '<1g' per 1 cup, while there are three protein powders from Vega with a 'mocha' flavor:  Essentials (5g/scoop) ; One (13g/scoop) ; Sport (6g/scoop) ... so it's not a straight conversion to grams.  It might be one of those points systems like Weight Watchers has (had?)

Comment: @Joe I didn't even realize that "silk unsweetened almond milk" is a brand. A cup of almond milk having 1 g was indeed unusual, and having less than 10 g of carbohydrates a day is an extreme ketogenic diet with lots of side effects, so I was also thinking of a unit from some dietary system, maybe Broteinheiten (I don't even know if BE are used in English speaking countries). At least a name for the unit is needed, then we can link to an explanation how it relates to other units.

Comment: @rumtscho it's pretty standard in US carbohydrate conscious groups to omit "gram"... "1 carb" is "one gram of carbohydrates". This is, essentially, identical to Lynds' answer.

Comment: @Catija : in looking at the [other answers, like spacebread's](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/55177/67), it's possible that this point system is possibly total carbohydrates minus the fiber.  In that case, Vega Essentials is ~1g/scoop (5g total, 4g fiber); Vega Sport is ~3g/scoop (6g total, 3g fiber).  These are approximate, as these numbers are rounded.  (Essentials might be 5.4g total, 3.5g fiber, so closer to 2g/scoop)

Comment: OK, so we have some evidence that the answer references grams, and some evidence against it. I still find it confusing, and would like to see the OP clarify.

Comment: @rumtscho what evidence goes against grams? Even Joe's explanation is still in grams... it's just total grams minus dietary fiber grams.

Comment: @Catija a diet which has less than 10 grams in carbohydrates per day is very unusual, even in low carb circles. And very hard to stay on for prolonged periods.

Answer (score 0):

Carbmaster milk is milk that has been put through a filtration process which removes most of the sugar (the carbohydrate in milk is all a form of sugar). It has one quarter the sugar of regular milk (3 g per cup) and is fat free.  I prefer some fat content, so I just add a little heavy cream (adds no sugar).  With this addition, Carbmaster tastes as good as any regular 2 percent milk I've ever had.  It is a product of the Kroger company, which sells it in its supermarkets, and also in a regional chain called Harris Teeter, found mainly in the Carolinas.  (Kroger stores are found in many states across the country).